# What is the maximum rate at which events are fired in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, mouseevent, dom-events

I am trying to troubleshoot some of the performance issues I am encountering in a simple pixel painter app I am making. When the mouse is held down and a div is being hovered over, that div should change its background color. Which it does! The issue is that when moving the mouse rapidly certain divs are skipped along semi-regulars intervals. This suggests to me some sort of sampling problem.

I would be interested in knowing what the maximum frequency of event firings are for a web browser and whether this is specified in some standard (related to, say, ES6).

**The situation for those who are interested:**
[image: Grid With Intervals]

Comment: Problem is in your code not the events

Answer (score 1):

More likely is that your painting code is still running when the next event comes in and that is dragging down your cpu. You need to cache just the mouse enter in the handler, and then do the painting work asynchronously to the events. Co-operative multitasking style.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not any standard for the rate at wich the events can be fired. As what I experienced that depends on a lot of factors incuding the current users machine power.

Look, I made the drawing in this canvas of two lines of dots at a fixed Y position and at the current X position. The upper one was updated whith a while loop as frequent as the script could, the other one was drawn with the mouseMoved event. As you can see, the result is pretty much the same (even the dots in the MouseMove one are sometimes more often)
[dots frecuency comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8rFi.png)
The time it takes for the event handler affects a lot, in fact I made the method to wait 1 second and then draw and the result was dots spaced for 5cm moving the mouse at the same speed.

So while the cpu is busy in an event handler it's more likely to not attend to new event triggers. My only recomendation is to stop the event propagation so it does not consume any resources and return false so the browser does not do any default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `<canvas>` can help you achieve a smoother behavior:

```js
const scale = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
const unit = 8;
const scaledUnit = unit * scale;
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const offsetLeft = canvas.offsetLeft;
const offsetTop = canvas.offsetTop;

let drawing = false;

canvas.setAttribute('width', canvas.offsetWidth * scale);
canvas.setAttribute('height', canvas.offsetHeight * scale);

canvas.onmousedown = (e) => {
  drawing = true;
  
  paintPixel(Math.floor((e.pageX - offsetLeft) / unit), Math.floor((e.pageY - offsetTop) / unit));
};

canvas.onmouseup = (e) => {
  drawing = false;
};

canvas.onmousemove = (e) => {
  if (drawing) {
    paintPixel(Math.floor((e.pageX - offsetLeft) / unit), Math.floor((e.pageY - offsetTop) / unit));
  }
};

canvas.onmouseleave = (e) => {
  paint = false;
};

function paintPixel(x, y) {
  ctx.fillRect(x * scaledUnit, y * scaledUnit, scaledUnit, scaledUnit);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

However, to completely avoid those gaps, you would have to draw a line from one cursor position to the next instead of painting an individual "pixel".

I would use [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to calculate all the points between consecutive events. Something like this:

```js
const scale = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
const unit = 8;
const scaledUnit = unit * scale;
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const offsetLeft = canvas.offsetLeft;
const offsetTop = canvas.offsetTop;

let drawing = false;
let lastX = null;
let lastY = null;

canvas.setAttribute('width', canvas.offsetWidth * scale);
canvas.setAttribute('height', canvas.offsetHeight * scale);

canvas.onmousedown = (e) => {
  drawing = true;
  lastX = Math.floor((e.pageX - offsetLeft) / unit);
  lastY = Math.floor((e.pageY - offsetTop) / unit);
  
  paintPixel(lastX, lastY);
};

canvas.onmouseup = (e) => {
  drawing = false;
};

canvas.onmousemove = (e) => {
  if (drawing) {
    const x = Math.floor((e.pageX - offsetLeft) / unit);
    const y = Math.floor((e.pageY - offsetTop) / unit);
    const w = Math.abs(x - lastX);
    const h = Math.abs(y - lastY);
    
    if (w === 0 && h === 0) {
      paintPixel(x, y);
    } else if (w > h) {
      lineLandscape(lastX, lastY, x, y);
    } else {
      linePortrait(lastX, lastY, x, y);
    }
  
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
  }
};

canvas.onmouseleave = (e) => {
  paint = false;
};

function paintPixel(x, y) {
  ctx.fillRect(x * scaledUnit, y * scaledUnit, scaledUnit, scaledUnit);
}

function lineLandscape(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
  if (x0 > x1) {
    [x0, x1] = [x1, x0];
    [y0, y1] = [y1, y0];
  }
  
  const dx = x1 - x0;
  const dy = Math.abs(y1 - y0);
  const yi = y0 > y1 ? -1 : 1;
  
  let D = 2 * dy - dx;  
  let y = y0;

  for (let x = x0; x <= x1; ++x) {
    paintPixel(x, y);
    
    if (D > 0) {
      y += yi;
      D -= 2 * dx;
    }
    
    D += 2 * dy;
  }
}

function linePortrait(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
  if (y0 > y1) {
    [x0, x1] = [x1, x0];
    [y0, y1] = [y1, y0];
  }
  
  const dx = Math.abs(x1 - x0);
  const dy = y1 - y0;
  const xi = x0 > x1 ? -1 : 1;
  
  let D = 2 * dx - dy;  
  let x = x0;

  for (let y = y0; y <= y1; ++y) {
    paintPixel(x, y);
    
    if (D > 0) {
      x += xi;
      D -= 2 * dy;
    }
    
    D += 2 * dx;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

You can also adapt that algorithm to work with your approach if you really need to use `<div>`s.